# Resizing svg with svg.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg, svg.js

I'm trying to resize several svgs by dragging with svg.js. I'm using Angular.

Draggable works fine but resizing doesn't work. I already searched the whole Internet for a solution but I could find nothing. Do you have an idea what could be wrong/ modified?

Code:

```js
this.svgwidget = SVG.get(this.widget.id);

this.svgwidget.move(this.widget.x, this.widget.y);
this.svgwidget.draggable({
        minX: 0,
        minY: 0,
        maxX: 150,
        maxY: 100,
        snapToGrid: 1
    })
    .on('click', (event: Event) => {
        this.editWidget.emit(this.widget);
    })
    .on('dragend', (event: Event) => {
        this.widget.x = this.svgwidget.x();
        this.widget.y = this.svgwidget.y();
    });

this.svgwidget.selectize()
    .resize({
        constraint: {
            minX: 0,
            minY: 0,
            maxX: 150,
            maxY: 100,
        }
    })
    .on('click', (event: Event) => {
        this.editWidget.emit(this.widget);
    })
    .on('dragend', (event: Event) => {
        console.log(event);
        this.widget.x = this.svgwidget.x();
        this.widget.y = this.svgwidget.y();
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible that svg plugins don't have *.d.ts file in their libraries and angular doesn't load them? Because I had this problem

Comment: Is the element selected? If this doesn't work already than resizing won't work either